# python 3: random.seed(): where to call it?

Tags: python, random, coding-style, python-3.x

I need to make sure all the randomness in my program is fully replicable. Where should I place a call to random.seed()?

I thought it should be in my `main.py` module, but it imports other modules that happen to use random functions.

I can carefully navigate through my imports to see which one is the first to execute, but the moment I change my code structure I will have to remember to redo this analysis again.

Is there any simple and safe solution?

Comment: Are you worried that the modules that use random functions are going to disturb replicability? As long as they don't use random.seed() themselves, it should be fine. If that's not your worry, why are you worried about what your modules happen to do?

Comment: Are you saying you don't have a top-level `main()` function that does the real work of the application?  Why not?

Comment: @Josh @S Lott: I do have `main`; it starts by saying: `import random`, `import anothermodule`, `random.random.seed()`. It's just that `anothermodule` happens to also `import random` and use functions from `random`, thus my seeding happens a bit too late.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is actually safe to execute code in the "import section" of your main module, so if you are unsure about importing other modules that might or might not use the random module, maybe bypassing your seed, you can of course use something like

```
import random
random.seed(seed_value)

import something
import else

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want random to be replicable, it's probably best to make an instance of [`random.Random`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/random.html) in your application, call `seed()` on that instance, and use that instance for your random numbers.

`random.random()` actually uses a singleton of the `random.Random` class, for convenience for people who don't care enough to make their own class instance. But that singleton is potentially shared with other modules that might want to call `random.random()` to generate random numbers for whatever reason. That's why in your case you're better off instantiating your own `random.Random` instance.

Quoting from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/random.html):

> The functions supplied by this module are actually bound methods of a hidden instance of the `random.Random` class. You can instantiate your own instances of `Random` to get generators that don’t share state.

Answer (score 1):

You could roll your own singleton that encapsulates random. You can then use [Python documentation on random](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) getstate and setstate to change the state of the random number generator. That would give your program two random number generators essentially.

Comment: Instead of random.random(), consider making a "singleton" of a random.WichmannHill instance, and use that throughout the code that needs to have reproducable results. All other modules that calls random.random() can keep doing so without you caring or knowing.